# Where to find current literature, especially dissertations, on complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Is there any public website or any other source which classify written master or doctoral thesis classify with respect to their content? Especially, I am going to make some research about complex analysis and I am intending to write a master thesis but since complex analysis is a very broad subject I just want to see what do people in that area doing currently. So could you tell me any online website I should check out?

Comment: This is probably unhelpful, but as I understand it standard complex analysis is sort of... over. Much like point-set topology, the core of the subject has pretty much been done to people's satisfaction. That's not to say there aren't still active research questions, its just not a large field.

Comment: At the very least, the field of multiple complex variables seems to be alive and kicking, though.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/list/math.CV/recent